# Create mongoid model with references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, reference, mongoid

I want to create model which is referenced to another:

```
class User  
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :name, :type => String
  belongs_to :post
end 

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :content, :type => String  
  has_one :author, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

But I am confused how to make mongoDB work accordingly to rules on model files (user.rb, post.rb).

First of all I have created model throw command line:

```
rails generate model User name:string
rails generate model Post content:string
```

Then I manually edited model files. I have added this line

```
belongs_to :post
has_one :author, :class_name => 'User'
```

Then I run code in one action:

```
post = Post.new
post.content = "text"
post.author = User.new
post.save!
```

As result in database I see only content field. No author field.

What should I do and what I am doing wrong?

[ANSWER]
I confused has_to and belongs_to places. So the correct models look like:

```
class User  
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :name, :type => String
  has_many :post
end 

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :content, :type => String  
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Everything else keep as in question.

Answer (score 0):

try to use existing user object instead of user User.new, and you can also try to use belongs_to instead of has_one, it stores the same data I guess, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Well to begin with I'd say it feels better to say a post belongs to a user rather than the opposite, but it's just a matter of choice.

What do you mean by

> "in database I see only content field. No author field."

If you just type "post" in the rails console you shouldn't see the author as it is a reference field.
If you want to see all the attributes, `post.attributes` will list everything, including references. and `post.attributes.inspect` will show you how it is stored in the database

Comment: Oh sorry the above only works for embedded objects.
Actually, you can see the "belongs_to" fields using this trick :

`post = Post.new

Post.find(post)`

I'm still looking for a way to display all the "has_many" references

Answer (score 0):

Its been six years but I´ll reply. The way I found to solve this issue was to pass the embedded model as a parameter in the new method. In my case it was an endpoint call so I would be receiving a user_id and would like to create a post `p = Post.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])`.

Doing this, when I save the new post it does the proper connection. I believe that, in the case of a new user, if you create the user before, save it and make the connection using the ID it should work as it did for me.